# C# ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a Tic Tac Toe 2D game in Unity but it gives me this error, anyone knows how to fix it?
heres my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Text[] buttonList;

    void Awake() {
        SetGameManagerReferenceOnButton();
    }

    void SetGameManagerReferenceOnButton() {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Length; i++) {
        BunkaScript bunkaScript = buttonList[i].GetComponent<BunkaScript>();
        if (bunkaScript != null) {
            bunkaScript.SetGameManagerReference(this);
        } else {
           
        }
    }
    }

    public string Hrac() { //hrac = Player
        return "?";
    }

    public void UkonciKolo() { // end turn
        Debug.Log("Ukonci kolo");
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the parameters to a method call is null - can you tell us which one? The only method calls that I see that include parameters are `SetGameManagerReference(this)` and `Log("Ukonci kolo")`, and there is no possible way those parameters could be null. See [mre].

Comment: When the code is run, it looks like a function expected a parameter but received a null reference instead. From your code, the only function with a parameter is `BunkaScript.SetGameManagerReference(GameManager)` and the question lacks that code. @gunr2171 the `SetGameManagerReference` could be internally calling a function and raising the exception

Comment: NullReferenceException != ArgumentNullException

Comment: @RandRandom none of the comments call it a `NullReferenceException`, and I agree the actual close reason is wrong, but I believe it should be closed because it lacks the code to reproduce the problem (a complete reproducible example of the problem).